# Xamarin Android C#: Populate ListView Custom Row With Data From SQLite Database

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, listview, xamarin

I'm tring to create a ListView which is fed data from an SQLite Database (pre-existing db file). The ListView uses a custom row which is one of the aspects which baffle me; How do I extract the data and then assign it to a TextView in the custom row?

I'm new to Xamarin, so would really appreciate any guidance you can give me on this, Thank you!

Current Dialog Box Error When Run:

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class      "md5c4f65b5cf99ab8e97737acf0f8ec7efd.DBHelper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/AppName.Droid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/AppName.Droid-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/AppName.Droid-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

'MainActivity':

```
public class EateriesActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Title = "Find An Eatery";
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Eateries);


        DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
        db.CreateDatabase();
        db.CreateTable();

        var items = db.GetData();
        var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.EateryList_ListView);

        listView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.Eatery_ListView_Row, items);
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter (is this necessary?):

```
class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Eatery>
{
    private List<Eatery> myItems;
    private Context myContext;
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Eatery> items)
    {
        myItems = items;
        myContext = context;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return myItems.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Eatery this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return myItems[position];
        }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(myContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Eatery_ListView_Row, null, false);
        }

        TextView placeName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.placeName);
        placeName.Text = myItems[position].Name;

        TextView placeTown = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.placeTown);
        placeTown.Text = myItems[position].Town;

        return row;
    }
}
```

Eatery:

```
public class Eatery
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Cuisine { get; set; }
}
```

DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper
{
    private static string DB_PATH = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    private static string DB_NAME = "EateryDB.db";

    public void CreateDatabase()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), dbPath);
    }

    public void CreateTable()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), dbPath);
        db.CreateTable<Eatery>();
    }

    public List<string> GetData()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), dbPath);
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in db.Table<Eatery>())
        {
            var place = item.Name.ToString(); item.Town.ToString();

            data.Add(place);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Are you actually asking how to connect to and get data from a SQlite database?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Hi. Its not actually that I'm having issues with its more the method of assigning the retrieved data to a TextView in the custom ListView row. Could you post a possible solution to my problem above if its that obvious please, would really appreciate your help? I've updated the code in the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your two version of code, I think what you need is adding data from your database to the `myItems`.

Then you can for example code like this:

```
List<Eatery> data = new List<Eatery>();
foreach (var item in db.Table<Eatery>())
{
     var place = item.Name.ToString();
     var location = item.Location.ToString();
     var rating = item.Rating;
     item.Town.ToString();
     data.Add(new Eatery() { PlaceName = place, PlaceLocation = location, PlaceRating = rating });
}
```

And finally add this data to your adapter as you did when you hard code:

```
MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, data);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I added the first section of code to the addData() method in DBHelper, then the ListViewAdapter class reference to the EateryActivity. Is there anything else? I get the same error as stated at the top of my post.

Comment: @E.Coder, your error suggests that your `DBHelper` class cannot be found, it is null, did you correctly initial it?

Comment: I have initiated it in the Main Activity...Does what I have done so far look correct or would you suggest a different way of connecting to the DB?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer...do I put the 'adapter' code in the Main Activity or in the MyListViewAdapter class? Thanks again.

Comment: @E.Coder, no, in your `EateriesActivity`, just check your earlier version code in the question, I mean you can simply replace your fake data with the data from your db.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I now get an error "no such table: Eatery". I have a DB called "EateryDB" and a table within it called "EateryDatabase" which I need to get the data from.

Comment: Been trying for over a month now with no luck :( Any other suggestions please? Determined to get it working!